# Foreach doesnt work in my View in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, foreach, view

```
public function getValues(Request $request){
            $typ=$request->get('typ');
            $stellentyp=$request->get('stellentyp');
            $bereich=$request->get('bereich');
            $abschluss=$request->get('abschluss');
            $user = DB::table('users')->get();
            $angebots = DB::table('angebots') ->orderBy('stellenname', 'asc');
            if(!empty($request->get('stellentyp'))){
                $angebots->where('stellentyp', $stellentyp);
            }
            $angebots->get();
            $row = $angebots->count();
            return view('user/angebots', compact('typ', 'stellentyp', 'bereich', 'abschluss', 'row', 'angebots', 'user'));
        }
```

this is my controller

```
{{$row}} Angebote insgesamt
    <div class="row">
        @foreach ($angebots as $angebot)
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 pt-4">
                <div class="card offer-card">
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ asset('uploads/avatars/' . $user[$angebot->firma -1]->avatar) }}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="text-j4y-dark praktikumstitel">{{ $angebot->stellenname }}</h4>
                        <a href="{{ route('angebot.details',['id'=>$angebot->firma]) }}">Jetzt mehr anzeigen »</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
```

and this is my view

but i got this error message:
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$firma (View: C:\wamp\sites\j4ylara\resources\views\user\angebots.blade.php)

if I put the get behind my first statement so like this

```
$angebots = DB::table('angebots') ->orderBy('stellenname', 'asc')->get();
```

but then the filter doesn't  work

I don't know how I can view my results

I only know this way

```
{{$angebot[1]->stellenname}}
```

but I want all my results so I use a foreach but it doesn't work

does anyone know why?

Comment: What does `dd($angebots);` give you? I won't test it but what if you wait to order your ORM buildup? So forget about the order by `$angebots = DB::table('angebots') ;` and then `$angebots->orderBy('stellenname', 'asc')->get();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following snippet

```
$angebots = DB::table('angebots') ->orderBy('stellenname', 'asc');
if(!empty($request->get('stellentyp'))){
    $angebots->where('stellentyp', $stellentyp);
}
$angebots->get();
```

You're doing `$angebots->get()` which *returns* the results of your query. You need to assign the results of your query to a variable and pass that into your view. You could do something like this:

```
$angebots = $angebots->get();
```

Which would assign the result of the query to `$angebots` and then you could use it in your view.

Personally, I would consider renaming `$angebots` to `$angebotsQuery` or something similar and then do this:

```
$angebotsQuery = DB::table('angebots') ->orderBy('stellenname', 'asc');
if(! empty($request->get('stellentyp'))){
    $angebotsQuery->where('stellentyp', $stellentyp);
}
$angebots = $angebotsQuery->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the Builder in `$angebot`. Try putting the results in a variable.

```
public function getValues(Request $request){
    $typ=$request->get('typ');
    $stellentyp=$request->get('stellentyp');
    $bereich=$request->get('bereich');
    $abschluss=$request->get('abschluss');

    $user = DB::table('users')->get();
    $angebots = DB::table('angebots') ->orderBy('stellenname', 'asc');
    if(!empty($request->get('stellentyp'))){
        $angebots->where('stellentyp', $stellentyp);
    }
    $angebots = $angebots->get();
    $row = $angebots->count(); //this will not cause an issue since the Collection has a count method

    return view('user/angebots', compact('typ', 'stellentyp', 'bereich', 'abschluss', 'row', 'angebots', 'user'));
    }
```